# Expecting a null returned from XML.value() in SQL, but getting 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm attempting to read a specific value from an xml parameter passed into a stored procedure.  A rough example of my code so far is below.

```
SET @SearchFilter = 
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <KeywordSearch xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SelfEmployed xsi:nil="true" />
 </KeywordSearch>'

SET @SelfEmployed  = @SearchFilter.query('/KeywordSearch/SelfEmployed[1]').value('/', 'bit')

SELECT @SelfEmployed
```

The issue I'm having is that, although the above correctly returns when the element contains a true or false value, where the element contains no value, and thus I'm expecting null, it returns false.  Is there a way to correctly obtain the datatype as a nullable bit value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change your XQuery to something like this:

```
SELECT @SearchFilter.value('(/KeywordSearch/SelfEmployed/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
```

then you'll get a `NULL` value back. Since you're checking to see whether or not the `<SelfEmployed>` node has any textual value, you should be interpreting the `.value()` as a string type - I'm using `varchar(100)` here - adapt as needed.

Comment: I'm attempting the parse the value of the /KeywordSearch/SelfEmployed element.  Where this element contains no value (as in the example), this should be returning a null.

My understanding was that the .value makes use of the T-SQL convert which defaults a null value to be null unless fed a sppecific style flag, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This worked without needing to change the datatype.  Seems making use of .value rather than .query and then calling text at the end of the node tree fixed the issue.

Thank-you very much!